# How can I create individual user pages with PHP?

Tags: php, url, variables, redirect

I have a site with a page called users.php that accepts the URL variable "username" and returns user information based on that variable. For example, the URL users.php?username=someuser will retrieve data for the user "someuser".
I am curious how to make an individual URl for each user, so that mysite.com/someuser redirects to users.php?username=someuser.

Can someone explain how to do this to me?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look for `.htaccess` and redirection if you are using an Apache server.

Comment: There are lot of questions and tutorials about it, consider looking for `pretty urls` , `seo url` , `.htaccess` , `rewrite rules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the .htaccess file.
Take a look [here](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html)

For Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
```

It will convert URLs like

```
site.com/user123/ or site.com/user123
```

to

```
site.com/user.php?username=user123
```

Comment: would be nice to actually share the example on SO and quote the site as your source, so many dead links i see on here. edit away and show 'how'

Comment: I thought it had something to do with htaccess, but I wasn't sure what exactly, thanks for the example!